# Looking for the fastest way to slice a row in a huge Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My program needs to fetch a row based on the value in a column from a huge Pandas Dataframe. The response time is critical. I use the most common way to do it, for example:

```py
df.loc[df['id'] == 500000, :]
```

Per `timeit` on my Mac it took 4 ms to complete the above operation on a dataframe with 1 million rows. But my goal is to reduce the time to like 0.4 ms. I once consider to convert this dataframe to a Set but Set is not ordered and does not natively support indexing or slicing. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm just shooting here, don't know if these are faster, but try: `df.query('id == 500000')` & `df[df['id'].isin(500000)]`

Comment: Consider making `id` your index.  Index lookup is *very* fast and it will avoid the linear time lookup you are doing now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets set this up:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": np.random.randint(100,size=(1000000,))})
```

Then let's benchmark some options. Your current boolean + `.loc`:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("df.loc[df['id'] == 50, :]", setup = "from __main__ import df", number=1000)
2.566220869999597
```

The query engine:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("df.query('id == 50')", setup = "from __main__ import df", number=1000)
14.591400260000228
```

Using the index as a separate lookup:

```
>>> idx = pd.Index(df['id'])
>>> timeit.timeit("df.loc[idx == 50, :]", setup = "from __main__ import df, idx", number=1000)
2.2155187300013495
```

Using the dataframe index for lookup:

```
>>> df.index = df["id"]
>>> timeit.timeit("df.loc[50, :]", setup = "from __main__ import df", number=1000)
2.625610274999417
```

And that `.isin()` idea that someone in the comments had:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("df.loc[df['id'].isin([50]), :]", setup = "from __main__ import df", number=1000)
9.542700138999862
```

Looks like with the exception of the query engine being slow (as expected) for a simple equality, you're not going to get much better than the lookup time you've got.

```
df_unique = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(1000000)})
```

Lets see how a unique ID might be helpful:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("df_unique.loc[df_unique['id'] == 50, :]", setup = "from __main__ import df_unique", number=1000)
1.9672015519990964
```

Then to a dict:

```
>>> df_unique.index = df_unique['id']
>>> df_dict = df_unique.to_dict(orient='index')
>>> timeit.timeit("df_dict[50]", setup = "from __main__ import df_dict", number=1000)
6.247700002859347e-05
```

Well, looks like this is a clear winner.

```
>>> timeit.timeit("pd.Series(df_dict[50])", setup = "from __main__ import df_dict, pd", number=1000)
0.2747819870000967
```

Even if you have to cast it back to a series for something this is an order of magnitude faster than before. (You also could map a series back into the dict very easily if needed and keep the speed of a dict lookup with no overhead)

Comment: Fortunately the ids in my dataframe are unique, so I can use your last solution by converting it to a dictionary. I will try it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Check how quickly works *df.query('id == 500000')*.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `df.id.values`:

Let's create a dataframe with 1000000 rows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(3)
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": np.random.randint(100,size=(1000000,))})
```

Method 1:

```
%%time
df.loc[df['id'] == 50, :]
#CPU times: user 6.64 ms, sys: 57 µs, total: 6.69 ms
#Wall time: 5.39 ms
```

[image: Output 1]

Method 2:

```
%%time
df.loc[df.id.values == 50, :]
#CPU times: user 3.97 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 3.97 ms
#Wall time: 2.82 ms
```

[image: Output 2]

*Note: in this example, the output dataframe has 9915 rows. Moreover, the speed seems to relate to the value you query and the original df structure.*

**Let's use timeit module to benchmark the test.**

Method 1:

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit("df.loc[df['id'] == 50, :]", setup = "from __main__ import df", number=1000)
#1.5578972157090902
```

Method 2:

```
timeit.timeit("df.loc[df.id.values == 50, :]", setup = "from __main__ import df", number=1000)
#1.3210897352546453
```